# styling the border in the bottom of a current menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, css

i want to add a border in the bottom of the current-menu-item div.
it is easy to do that with just adding the border in the div.
my problem it that i want the border to be something like 98% of the div width and to be able to change the border's position a bit to the top because if the border is in the bottom, he is escaping from the menu height.

the css code for the current menu:

```
.menu ul li.current-menu-item>a, .left_bar_list li.current-menu-item>a {
background-color: #;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid #E88C02;
}
```

the php code (if someone need):

```
        <div class="menu">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container' => '', 'depth' => '2' ));?>
    </div>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a pseudo-element:

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
}
.element:after {
  content: ''; /* Generate a pseudo-element with no content */
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  right: 1%;
  bottom: 0; /* Increase this to achieve the "a bit to the top" */
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help. maybe i was not clear about what i need. in my menu i have Home and categories (for example). now, when i am clicking on Home ill go to the home page and then there is a border (like i want) under the Home item. the pseudo is like (a: hover) and i mean after the item was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the border to be something other than the complete width of the div then it would be better to use a pseudo element like `::after`.

You'll have way more control over a pseudo element than a regular css border.

[Here's an example of that.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lduk8avy/)

Comment: thank you for the help. maybe i was not clear about what i need. in my menu i have Home and categories (for example). now, when i am clicking on Home ill go to the home page and then there is a border (like i want) under the Home item. the pseudo is like (a: hover) and i mean after the item was clicked.